# Collection of Intuitive / Visual Derivations of Mathematical Concepts and Formulas

Tags: reference-request, intuition, visualization

I find it difficult to simply memorize mathematical formulas in engineering without understanding what it means and what the result is like, but I realized that many mathematical relationships can be explained visually and by intuition, and I was searching for a reference to provide such great helps to students. Would anybody know of a title of a book or a download site? This would be a great help to students like me who struggle through engineering math. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just *Google* the appropriate term or phrase, and then to click on the “*Images*” tab: [Binomial Theorem](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/BinomialTheorem.png), [Pythagorean Theorem](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5f/Diagram_of_Pythagoras_Theorem.png), [The sum of the first *n* odd numbers is $n^2$](http://www.9math.com/images/oddsum.png), [The sum of the first *n* numbers is $\frac{n(n+1)}2$](http://i1.wp.com/mathandmultimedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/sum-of-natural-numbers2.png?fit=1024%2C1024) , [Disk or Circle Area](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Equation_in_circle_proved_by_the_method_of_indivisibles.gif), etc.